# [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipenv-install

I have a requirement.txt looks like,

```
# ~/projects/pip-env-test/requirement.txt
Django==2.2
```

and now I ran the command, `pipenv install -r requirements.txt --python 3.6`

and now I have got the error,

> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2

We know, the Django==2.2 is there and it seems the flag **`--python 3.6`** is not using by the `pipenv` command.

> complete error traceback

```
  % pipenv install -r requirements.txt --python 3.6                                                                                                                                                          !7968
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (0a73ee)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (0a73ee)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 1/1 — 00:00:00
An error occurred while installing django==2.2 --hash=sha256:7c3543e4fb070d14e10926189a7fcf42ba919263b7473dceaefce34d54e8a119 --hash=sha256:a2814bffd1f007805b19194eb0b9a331933b82bd5da1c3ba3d7b7ba16e06dc4b! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 252, in install
[InstallError]:       site_packages=state.site_packages
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2062, in do_install
[InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1314, in do_init
[InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 901, in do_install_dependencies
[InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 796, in batch_install
[InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[InstallError]:   File "/home/jpg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 703, in _cleanup_procs
[InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-txy_9wyg-requirements/pipenv-aq47p_5k-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26, 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-txy_9wyg-requirements/pipenv-aq47p_5k-requirement.txt (line 1))
ERROR: Couldn't install package: django
 Package installation failed...
  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/1 — 00:00:00
```

**Note:** I am using `pipenv==2020.6.2` at this moment

### Update-1

I tried to run the same command, after

1. exiting from virtualenv
2. deleting `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`

But, I have got another error,

```
  % pipenv install -r requirements.txt --python 3.6                                                                                                                                                          !7979
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/jpg/projects/pip-env-test/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3.6m (3.6.9) to create virtualenv…
⠹ Creating virtual environment...ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_file_on_disk'

✘ Failed creating virtual environment 

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: 
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

Comment: In your log message, pipenv says it detected an activated virtual environment. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I have tried the same without venv (see the `Update-1` section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log says you're using Python 2.7, which is EOL:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020.
```

Django 2.x+ doesn't support Python 2 at all (as you can see from the log, available Django versions for Python 2 are 1.1.3, [...], 1.11.27, 1.11.28, 1.11.29).

That's why it's impossible to satisfy a requirement for Django 2.2 on Python 2.x.

Comment: That makes sense, But what about the flag I used `--python 3.6 ` ?

Comment: Based on googling the error (you did that, didn't you?), it looks like your Python 3.6 environment is screwed up with multiple versions of `virtualenv` conflicting with each other. https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1876